# Is there a way to read in a sample of an Rda file?

Tags: r, shiny, rda

I have a very large dataset in an Rda file that I want to use for a shiny app but since it's so large I'm thinking of just taking a sample of the file and read that in. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/load-save-and-rda-files/

Comment: If there is a way to save a 'very large dataset' in `.csv` or something like SQLite, I'd go with that approach. You can read csv's very fast with data.table's `fread`, and you can execute SQL easily in R.